# Call ActionController action & render template without a path in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I want to process logic in one action.

If a certain block is true, I want to call another action so that its logic runs and then render the corresponding view for that action.

Right now I am doing

```
def conditional_action
  Foo.bar!
  render action: :conditional_action
end

def process_logic
  if @baz == 1
    conditional_action
  end
end
```

How do I avoid the third line?

Comment: what third line do you want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the statement:

```
redirect_to  :action => any_action, :params => your_params
```

Comment: Redirect to can't find the route